# php `require()` a file that has another `require()`

Tags: php

Alright, here is the problem:

- /dbh/dbh.php -> My DB connection handler.
- /shared/header.php -> My header that I want to include in most of my pages.
- /index.php -> My Main Page
- /src/home/home.php -> Main Page after Log-in

You have the project structure above, here is my code:

This is how I require `dbh.php` in my `header.php`:

```
require('dbh/dbh.php');
```

Then, inside `index.php`:

```
require 'shared/header.php';
```

And, inside `home.php`:

```
require '../../shared/header.php';
```

Code works fine when I am working in `index.php`, but whenever I am trying to run `home.php` I get this error:

```
Warning: require(dbh/dbh.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shared/header.php on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'dbh/dbh.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shared/header.php on line 4
```

I realize that this is due to relative `require()` pathing from each file and how it works, but I am not sure how I can use some static pathing for requiring files. I tried doing some research, but I can't wrap my head around how `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` works and not sure if those would works in this case.

Comment: On a side note, if you're going to include files some of which include the same file, then you might want to use `require_once()` instead.

Comment: @RoAchterberg you mean I should use `require_once()` in `header.php` right?

Comment: Yes, but see my answer for _how to use_ `require_once()` in each of the cases you describe.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefixing your `require()`s with `__DIR__` enables you to provide paths relative to the directory the respective script resides in, like so:

```
// Was: require('dbh/dbh.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../dbh/dbh.php');

// Was: require 'shared/header.php';
require(__DIR__ . '/shared/header.php');

// Was: require '../../shared/header.php';
require(__DIR__ . '/../../shared/header.php');
```

Comment: Inside `/shared/header.php`, OP would need to use `__DIR__.'/../dbh/dbh.php`

Comment: @Reed, yes! Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`__DIR__` refers to the current directory. So in `/shared/header.php`, `__DIR__` is `/shared`. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` refers to the root document for your request (something like `/home/user/public_html` or `/var/www/html/mysite.com/`. So you might use `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dbh/dbh.php'`

I'd go with a more re-useable approach, though.

In a file at `/setup.php`, you could use constants like:

```php
define('HEADER_PATH', __DIR__.'/shared/header.php');
define('DBH_PATH', __DIR__.'/dbh/dbh.php');
// and any other paths you need
```

Which are then used like: `require DBH_PATH;`.

Another approach (my preference) would be a class with static properties.
We'll say this is at `/MyServer.php`, so can be included any time with `require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MyServer.php';`

```php
class MyServer {
    static public $dbh_path = __DIR__.'/dbh/dbh.php';
    static public $header_path = __DIR__.'/shared/header.php';
}
```

Then as long as `/MyServer.php` is included on every request, you can call from any file `require MyServer::$dbh_path` & get the full path.

If you continue to be confused by `__DIR__` or `__FILE__`. Just throw the following in a script and run the script:

```php
var_dump(__DIR__);
var_dump(__FILE__);
exit;
```

Should help give you a sense of it.

Comment: Your solution looks great, but since I am quite new, I took the approach suggested by @Ro Achterberg which is easier to implement for a beginner like me. Either way, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Now when I got to know php a bit more, this solution looks very appealing. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)